# What does ** mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

What is `**` (two asterisks) used for in Python?

Like, `exampleVariable = 5 ** 5`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note: `**` in `**kwargs` means something different.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`**` is used as exponent. So `2 ** 2` is 2 to the second power, or `3 ** 3` is 3 to the third power, or 27.

Answer (score 2):

It is the operator for exponentiation. `5 ** 5` means "five to the power of five"